# When did it become illegal to use lead solder in residential plumbing?

Tags: plumbing

I'm looking for a citation on when the requirements to use lead-free solder in residential plumbing took effect.

Why? On 06/09/2009 a local plumbing company re-plumbed the house I live in.  Today we had lead testing done and found:

- Pipes: trace amount of lead
- Brass Fittings: 6.25%
- Solder: .7%

The fitting at 6.25% was legal at the time.
The pipes are fine.
But that solder number seems quite high for 2009 in California.

A fine fact sheet is at http://www.dtsc.ca.gov/PollutionPrevention/upload/lead-in-plumbing-fact-sheet.pdf but it does not give the history.

Comment: The factsheet you linked to shows that it was released in Feb 2009.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main site before your link shows that is was in [Jan 2009](http://www.dtsc.ca.gov/pollutionprevention/leadinplumbing.cfm) (par 3)
, with the regulations before 2010 being 0.2% for lead solder.